# How to use Javers in reactive spring?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-programming, audit, javers

I want to use Javers for entities changes auditing in my reactive spring project with MongoDB. 
Can anyone help me with configurations please ?

Answer (score 1):

I have asked for it's support with reactive MongoDB and the bad news is, it does not support reactive MongoDB as of now.

See:https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/672

Comment: Corrected Link: https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/672